# Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.android.camera.CropImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

My application using Image croping and running under some of mobile, however it is giving following error specially while running with Samsung mobile version 4.0 or higher. Complete error log as under.

Code
{
    public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter

```
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
```

}

```
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file         line #26: Error inflating class com.android.camera.CropImageView
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at                         android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at com.project.ugvcl.BillingGenerationActivity$CropOptionAdapter.getView(BillingGenerationActivity.java:3361)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2452)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1161)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12865)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12865)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12865)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12865)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12865)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2242)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12865)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.camera.CropImageView
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
06-10 15:03:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(2035):     ... 40 more
```

Comment: post ur question proper way...

Comment: if you dont post your code then how can you expect that we will solve your problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `com.android.camera.CropImageView` in your `crop_selector` XML layout but such a view class doesn't exist in the platform.

(There's one in the Gallery app but you shouldn't be using it like this. There's no guarantees that manufacturers include particular platform apps. Usually they want to replace them with their own. If your code ever worked, it's just a coincidence.)

If you have added a library that contains an implementation of `CropImageView`, use the full package name of that library's implementation instead.