# Android emulator crashes with FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, simulator

When I start the simulation of my app I get the following error. Does any one know where I am going wrong?

```
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58): HistoryRecord{525864f0 com.example.iwe/.ui.splash.SplashActivity} he10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2165)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2220)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1407)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:894)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:9007)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:570)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:79)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     ... 13 more
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010059 a=-1}
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-02 20:50:41.241: WARN/WindowManager(58):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:91)



10-02 13:29:47.983: ERROR/dalvikvm(279): Could not find class 'com.example.iwe.utils.ActivityLifecycleHandler', referenced from method com.example.iwe.App.onCreate
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.iwe.utils.ActivityLifecycleHandler
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at com.example.iwe.App.onCreate(App.java:32)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4244)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-02 13:29:52.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(279):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Manifest xml: Please correct me where i am missed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.example.iwe"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.iwe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.iwe.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application

        android:name="com.example.iwe.App"
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.landing.LandingActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/lgn_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.signup.SignUpActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/sup_sign_up"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_logo"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.friends.FriendDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/frd_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.mediacall.CallActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.chats.NewDialogActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/ndl_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.chats.PrivateDialogActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.chats.GroupDialogActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.chats.GroupDialogDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/gdd_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.chats.GroupDialogActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/prf_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.chats.AddFriendsToGroupActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/afg_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.chats.GroupDialogDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.settings.ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/cpw_change_password_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.forgotpassword.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/fpw_forgot_password_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.agreements.UserAgreementActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/uag_user_agreement_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.signup.SignUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBmoKFbTyrK96fjzIqY7v9C_wNNqtSl_3w"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.iwe" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.QBService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.example.iwe.caching.DatabaseProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.iwe"
            android:exported="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Manifest xml: Please correct me where i am missed.

Comment: You have a problem in an XML file :P

Comment: Please show your xml file

Comment: Please post your project structure and any code you suspect to be causing the problem.

Comment: @X'Factor Please mention wich xml file he should show

Comment: you have error in the xml where some drwable resources are missing show your xml

Comment: Check you logcat 

here is the arror Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):

Comment: What is your `ActivityLifecycleHandler` class? Is it library class or activity class?

Comment: Xfactor : yeah its a class

Comment: Up vote this as it has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Check you layout

here is the arror Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you might not have made the run configuration. Goto run configuration and select the project you want to run and try it should work.

Comment: Hi karthik every time i am doing lik u mentioned. It throwing classnotfounddef and Inflate exception

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137660/error-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-26-error-inflating similar problem discussed here this could help

Answer (score 0):

Your Question in wrong as Your app is uploaded in emulator and app is crashing as you are having some problems with your layout inflation please checkout your layout and code. Please be specific while asking questions.